# why is it giving numbers as output instead of elements in the array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
char[] np={'a','s','d','f'};
System.out.println(np[1]+np[np.length-1]);

// this print statement is giving output:217

System.out.println(""+np[1]+np[np.length-1]);
// this print statement is giving output:af
```

I just want to know why the first one is giving numbers as output ?
and this is in java.

Comment: Because character is converted to it's computer representation value (int equivalent) and added to the length. If you converted np[1] to a string and left the rest of the same you should no longer see this issue.

Comment: Because, on bytecode level, all primitves that are "`<= int`" are converted to `int`. Thus, `char`s get upcasted to `int` (by converting them to their UTF8 value) before they are "added". In the second example, the `"" + np[1]` is evaluated first and since the left-handed side of the binary operator is a `String`, the right-handed side must be converted to a `String` as well and gives the correct output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'s' + 'f'` will convert each character to its byte representation based on the encoding and auto convert it to an `int` value. These are based on the [widening primitive conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html) rules. Basically, `char` is treated as a more specific type of `int` and when added together, the more general of the two (`int`) will be the type returned.

To solve this, you can convert one of the variables to a type which will prevent the compiler from interpreting it as an `int` addition. One way would be to add a `String` at the start as you have above. Another way could be to modify `np[1]` to `String.valueOf(np[1])` in the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax `np[1]+np[np.length-1` is converted to `'s' + 'f'`, which is treated by java as an addition operation. Hence JAVA converts 's' and 'f' to their **[ASCII integer](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html)** values 115 and 102 and adds them to 217.

On the second statement including a **double quote("")** locks that value as a string and hence, JAVA no longer treats the operation as an addition but a string combination, thus the result.

Answer (score 0):

With the new String formatted, You can simplify this.

```java
char[] np = { 'a', 's', 'd', 'f' };
System.out.println("%s%s".formatted(np[1], np[np.length - 1]));
```

By default, np[1] trying to use the ASCII code value `int+int`